# Maven ignoring resources in GitLab CI

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to get Maven to package a simple RESTful project that uses variables from a .properties file within GitLab CI. The problem is that I can't get Maven to correctly package the .properties file.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
    - build
    - package
    - deploy

variables:
    PROPERTIES_VALUE: $PROPERTIES_VALUE

services:
    - docker:dind

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: 

    # Getting a value from $PROPERTIES_VALUE doesn't work either
    - printf 'greeting = $PROPERTIES_VALUE \ntest = "f"' > Foo/src/main/resources/application.properties
    - cat Foo/src/main/resources/application.properties
    - "mvn package -B -f Foo/pom.xml"

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - Foo/target/*.jar
```

Above I try to create and populate application.properties, the file gets created but maven ignores it. I try to get PROPERTIES_VALUE from "Secret variables" but it doesn't work.

I have also added the folder to my pom.xml:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Maven still ignores my properties file. Everything works fine in my IDE on my own machine, but I can't get it to work at all on GitLab Runners.

This is the java class that is using the application.properties file:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

@Controller
public class Greeting {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public @ResponseBody String greeting(){
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        String greeting;
        try {

            input = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties");

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out
            greeting = prop.getProperty("greeting");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            greeting = "failed";
        }
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

As you can see, every time I try the Maven packaged jar file, it just returns "failed" every time and says that such a file does not exist.

I should also add that I ignore certain files in my GitLab repo so all I have pushed are 2 classes, the pom.xml file  and an empty resources folder.

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: First changing or adding a property file which is not part of the checked in code is a really a bad idea...Furthermore during a maven build the property files will automatically being copied into `target/classes` and will be packaged into the resulting jar file...but can not being accessed via files..Usually `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/application.properties")`.. cause the `src/main/..` will not be available in the packaged jar file at all...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I ask why changing or adding a property file would be a bad idea? Is this just bad practice? I am trying to get my code to use a few secret variables to access a database for example, but I cannot have them simply in my code at build time. I figured that using .properties file was the best way to go, do you have a better alternative?

Comment: These things should be given to the running application at runtime and not being part of the application via property files....